# Displaying data from list<string> on asp.net webpage?

Tags: asp.net, html

```
 <table id="table1" >
       <% var list=this.GetData(); 
       for (int i=0;i<list.Count();i++)
       { %>
      <tr>
          <td>        
           <% list[i].ToString(); %> //list items are not shown on webpage
          </td>
       </tr>

       <%}
       %>           
    </table>
`
```

Comment: Please be more specific, are you using webforms, mvc? Do you get an error message? What is your input and what do you want as output? what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is your question? Which technologies are you using? What is going wrong? Do you get an error or a wrong result?

Comment: What is the return type of `GetData()` ?

Comment: i am working with simple webforms.

Comment: I didnt get any error. GetData() returns list<string> the problem is list[i].ToString(); output is not going to display in the webpage

Comment: Shouldn't this be `<%= list[i].ToString(); %>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Simply use `<%: list[i] %>` instead of `<% list[i].ToString(); %>`

```
<table id="table1">
        <% var list = this.GetData();
           for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: list[i] %>
                //list items are not shown on webpage
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%}
        %>
</table>
```

To know more about Asp.net inline tags [go here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx).

But you should consider `Repeater` and other `data binding controls` provided by Microsoft already for this purpose.

Comment: It's better if you can specify exactly what change you are suggesting, otherwise we have to compare line by line to see exactly what the change is

Comment: @ImmanKhalid Well I don't think it should give any error, What's the error by the way, Try using `=` in place of `:`.

Comment: @Imman, `<%: %>` was only added to ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET MVC 2 ([see here for details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)) as a shorthand to `<%=Server.HtmlEncode(...)%>`.  Depending on what version of ASP.NET your using, as yogi say, try using `<%=...%>` instead

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [asp.net data controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567.aspx).

There are far better ways to bind data to your page in asp.net.